# Ethernet connection of pi is not detected by laptop

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, setup, laptop

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and I'm trying to use my laptop screen as display for the Pi. I had followed various tutorials for this none of it is working. I found that laptop couldn't detect the Pi when connected to the Ethernet port and even not blinking on either side port when connected. When I connected them using a router, even the router couldn't detect the Pi. What can be solution for this?

Comment: Is the Pi powered?  Has it booted?  What IP address has been assigned to the Pi?

Comment: How to assign ip address to pi? I m new to the Pi. I have just wrote IMG file on SD card(8GB) using win32 and inserted SD card into pi. Thank you !

Comment: I'm not aware of a laptop with a **HDMI-IN** port. You have to use a HDMI monitor or tv-set to connect to the pi or [operate the pi headless](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=74176).

Comment: @akshayhadawale By default the Pi will expect a DHCP server at the other end of the Ethernet link (to dynamically supply an IP address).  If your laptop doesn't perform that role (which it won't by default) you will need to give the Pi a static IP address.

Comment: If you are not seeing link lights on either end, you don't have an ethernet connection at the most basic level. Do you have a power LED on the RPi? Have you tried connecting a display to the RPi to verify it is booting?

Answer (score 0):

Modern ethernet devices usually support [Auto-Mdi-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto_MDI-X).

If for whatever reason this doesn't work or isn't supported you'll need a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) directly connecting the two.

Or use a device like a hub/switch/router to connect them with normal straight through patch cables.

For the router not detecting the pi - check with a different cable, the one you used might be broken.

Comment: I have used three different cables, but result was same.  Can you refer a good and trusted tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0):

Order matters here! The same thing happened to me. The solution turned out to be to first connect to the router, then insert the card, and then power on the raspberry. If you insert the card or connect via ethernet cable after it has been powered on then it may not work.